# Heroku Error with RoR App. (Devise?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I recently added a user avatar feature to the Devise edit.html page of my app. The feature (entire app) is working, locally.

Now that I have pushed to Heroku, the User Profile page (devise edit.html) is creating errors that I do not understand or know how to tackle.

I have tried to rake db:migrate on Heroku, and do get deprecation warnings, but I don't think they are the reason for my troubles, because everything works fine, locally.

DEPRECATION WARNING: 
You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)
DEPRECATION WARNING: 
You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from  at /app/Rakefile:7)

Related log:

```html
2015-01-21T19:01:16.221350+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered devise/registrations/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223471+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223480+00:00 app[web.1]:     9:   <div><%= image_tag @user.avatar %></div>
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223474+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error ( isn't precompiled):
2015-01-21T19:01:16.203961+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/edit" for 71.9.233.133 at 2015-01-21 19:01:16 +0000
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223477+00:00 app[web.1]:     7:   <%= f.file_field :avatar %></div>
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223479+00:00 app[web.1]:     8:   <br />
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223483+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:   <br />
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223475+00:00 app[web.1]:     6:   <div><%= f.label :avatar %><br />
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223482+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:   
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223485+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: 
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223487+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb__33245494095269574_70255842973360'
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223489+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_devise_registrations_edit_html_erb__33245494095269574_70255842973360'
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223490+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-01-21T19:01:16.223492+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-01-21T19:01:16.210980+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
2015-01-21T19:01:16.221599+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10.4ms
```

Relevant HTML

```html
<div><%= f.label :avatar %><br />
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %></div>
  <br />
  <div><%= image_tag @user.avatar %></div>
  
  <br />
```

Thank you for any guidance and assistance.

Comment: please try to update environments/production.rb file, config.serve_static_assets = true

Comment: rjackson, thanks for the idea. Not sure it is applicable. I am fairly certain that my trouble is indeed related to precompile and am chasing that.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a precompile error with the avatar assets. Try running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` and then pushing again.

You could also try adding Heroku's Rails 12Factor gem (https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) to your gemfile in the production group. This makes serving static assets a bit easier.

[This article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline) might also be of some help.

Comment: OK, i tried the command you suggested, which resulted in a series of errors. I have installed the 12Factor gem and am now reviewing the referenced article. Here are the errors from the command you provided. Thank you for the help. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/69497751/prodPrecompilErrors.txt

Comment: That's a known error with the sass gem. Try downgrading the version of sass in your gemfile (`gem 'sass', '3.2.13'`).